# Design a job scheduler for subscription system

Tags: mysql, node.js, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I have to develop/use a scheduler in my NodeJS project to check if any subscriptions need to be renewed. Job needs to run once every day and check my database if 'enddate' of a any user subscription record falls on that day. If it is, run a piece of logic to renew it (i have my own renew logic which doesnt depend on any external services like payment providers/gateways).

Application will be in cloud which means all my app instances have to be stateless. Database (MySQL) is the only stateful part of the system and Renew logic has to run only once.

How can i do this ?

My database table row for a subscription looks like this:

```
Id: 1, User: John Doe, Plan: Monthly Premium, Start Date: 1-10-2015, End Date: 30-10-2014, status : "ACTIVE"
```

Problems:

1.) Trigger job running logic everyday - Easy to solve in nodejs with setInterval or a scheduler library

2.) Running a worker or a piece of code that checks the db and renews it - This needs to happen only once per user subscription. Many instances can potentially run the renew logic at the same time when daily scheduler triggers the process. Not sure how to solve this part of the problem.

Comment: not sure what is really the question here. if it is "easy to solve" then why are you asking?

Comment: Did you read the entire question ? did u see the second part of the problem ?

Comment: indeed I did and as a matter of fact there is no question in the second part only statement that you re not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution consists of a shell script, put in your crontab, that would run each day.
This script would do :

- Using a sql statement or stored procedure, find records where subscription
  end date is today
- For those records, apply your logic. (send email or anything else)
- Flag the record to indicate that a something has been done
  for this user (and put in another field the process date).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can create a worker and use [`node-cron`](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to trigger subscription expire everyday.
2. i'm not sure what renew process does. you can use lock something until the renew process complete and release it. I was thinking i would use [`redlock`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock)

Comment: he is using mysql not redis

Comment: That's okay, I am using redis on my stack as well for app level caching, i can use it. I don't fully understand what redlock does though..

Comment: @Koder "Distributed locks are a very useful primitive in many environments where different processes must operate with shared resources in a mutually exclusive way." http://redis.io/topics/distlock

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), but it requires a MongoDb to maintain its state. If you are okay with adding one more DB, then you can give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks, i just saw Agenda, Adding MongoDb is the only problem. It looks like it solves my problem otherwise.